# Python pandas cross-selection equvialent with .loc and slices

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following panda data frame with the multi-index('timestamp', 'robot', 'side'):

```
 timestamp robot   side    strength    armor    health
 23958722  robot_1 left    100         20      100
                   right   200         25      100
           robot_2 left    100         25      90
                   right   80          10      19
           robot_3 right   40          20      200
           robot_4 left    100         100     20
 1424121   robot_1 left    90          19      100
           robot_2 left    90          25      10
```

1. Is it possible to use (index) slices and .loc[] to achieve the same result as this cross-selection?

   df.xs(('robot_1', 'left'), level=('robot', 'side'), drop_level=False)
2. Would the selection with .loc[] and slices be faster than .xs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution is:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 'robot_1', 'left'), :]
```

But the execution speed is almost the same (check yourself).

Note that this time you have to specify also the column indexer (*:*).